# C# / JS -- Как соединить сервер на node.js и клиент на C# через сокет?

Tags: c#, node.js, сокет, socket.io

Для node.js Есть хорошее решение - socket.io, однако его разработчики за 8 с лишним лет так и не додумались написать хоть какую то имплементацию для C#. Есть другие варианты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположу, что аналогом Socket.io в шарпе является SignalR.

Впрочем, если речь идёт именно о сокетах, то есть класс Socket, с которым можно работать.

Суть Socket.io и SignalR в том, чтобы переключать способ соединения в зависимости от поддержки браузером. Если ты контролируешь обе порграммы, точнее знаешь, что они поддерживают сокеты, нет смысла иметь полный клиент для свех видов связи - достаточно выбрать сокеты и пользоваться ими.

Comment: Мне надо, чтобы и клиент и сервер могли в любой момент времени отправлять друг другу сообщения. Когда и клиент и сервер у меня были на JS с socket.io это не было проблемой.

Comment: @Eevee, не вижу портиворечий с тем, что я сказал.

Comment: Да. Оно мне подходит.