# 502 bad gateway donationalerts

Tags: javascript, c#, веб-программирование, websocket, socket.io

Всем привет, решил написать программу для обработки донатов на donationalerts, работают они через виджет в виде страницы и через F12 я понял что получают и обрабатывают запросы через javascript socket.io, там был адрес их WebSocket сервера (wss://socket.donationalerts.ru:443), в браузере всё работет (те приходят уведомления о донате и само подключение сокетов), при попытке подключения посредством ClientWebSocket C# выбрасывается исключение:

WebException: Удаленный сервер возвратил ошибку: (502) Недопустимый шлюз.

Погуглив я понял что это может быть из-за отсутствия проксирования вебсокетов ngnix тк протокол wws, а при просмотре декомпилированной версии ClientWebSocket я увидел что протокол запроса меняется с wws на https, но опять таки порт у https и wss один и тот же 443. Но тогда почему библиотека socket.io работает, внутрь неё не лез так как в js не разбираюсь. Пожалуйста подскажите в чём может быть проблема, и если я несу откровенный бред пожалуйста поправьте.

Comment: Может им есть разница с какого хоста идет подключение?

Comment: @tym32167  что вы подразумеваете под хостом?

Comment: Не так выразился. Я просто предположил, что клиент может высылать адрес открытой в браузере страницы, чтобы сервер принимал не все подряд подключения, а только те, что с веб страницы идут. Хотя я не в теме, возможно тоже несу ерунду.

Comment: Клиент socket.io работает, потому что на сервере тоже socket.io.
Попробуйте поискать какой-нибудь специальный клиент
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/931780/c-js-Как-соединить-сервер-на-node-js-и-клиент-на-c-через-сокет

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/971760/c-создание-соединения-с-donationalerts-с-помощью-сокетов

Comment: @PsiHamster а почему тогда в ответе от сервера выбрасывается исключения где один из head-ров ответа от сервера server: ngnix? Это из-за того что запрос идёт на https? И спасибо за подсказку сейчас попробую